# Tests failing, when reading and writing a custom object from and to a stringstream

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, ostream, istream

There are no syntax errors and this is not the full code for Pixel_test.cpp and Pixel.cpp.

I only have the full header file.

The test that is failing, is the `assert(actual == correct);`.

I was thinking, that the problem is stemming from the `Pixel.cpp` file in the `std::ostream&` and `std::istream&`.

I have spent hours, trying to see why this test is not working, so I came here to get some help.

**Pixel_test.cpp:**

```
   stringstream in, out;
   string correct;
   Pixel pix;
   pix.set(5,3,2);
   correct = 5,3,2;
   out << pix;
   string actual = out.str();
   assert(actual == correct);
   in << (6,4,6);
   in >> pix;
   assert(pix.getRed() == 6);
   assert(pix.getBlue() == 6);
   assert(pix.getGreen() == 4);
```

**Pixel.cpp:**

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Pixel& pix)
{
     int r, g, b;
     r = pix.getRed();
     g = pix.getGreen();
     b = pix.getBlue();
     out << r << g << b;
     return(out);
}
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& out, Pixel& pix)
{
     int r, g, b;
     pix.setRed(r);
     pix.setGreen(g);
     pix.setBlue(b);
     out >> r >> g >> b;
     return out;
}
```

**Pixel.h:**

```
#ifndef PIXEL_H
#define PIXEL_H

namespace imagelab
{
    class Pixel
    {
     public:
        Pixel( int r=0, int g=0, int b=0 );     
        void set( int r, int g, int b );
        void setRed( int r );
        void setGreen( int g );
        void setBlue( int b );
        int getRed( ) const;
        int getGreen( ) const;
        int getBlue( ) const;

     private:
        int rval;   // red 0-255
        int gval;   // green 0-255
        int bval;   // blue 0-255
    };

    bool operator== (const Pixel& pix1, const Pixel& pix2);
    bool operator!= (const Pixel& pix1, const Pixel& pix2);
    std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const Pixel& pix);
    std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& in, Pixel& pix);
}

#endif
```

Comment: Did you print `actual` and `correct` to the console (or look at their values with a debugger) to see what they were? And unless `correct = 5,3,2;` lost the quotes around a string literal, you're assigning the character with ASCII value 2 to the string.

Comment: What is the type of variable `correct`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `assert(actual == correct);` to work, both `string`s should be exactly the same, which is not true in your case.

So, replace:

```
correct = 5,3,2;
```

in `Pixel_test.cpp` with:

```
correct = "5,3,2";
```

and also replace:

```
out << r << g << b;
```

in `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Pixel& pix)` with:

```
out << r << ',' << g << ',' << b;
```

to render the same output for `out << pix;`.

By making the above changes your `assert(actual == correct);` would stop failing.

But, the `asserts`s after that may fail because, when you call `in>>pix;` this function gets called:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& out, Pixel& pix)
{
 int r, g, b;
 pix.setRed(r);
 pix.setGreen(g);
 pix.setBlue(b);
 out >> r >> g >> b;
 return out;
}
```

And we can clearly see that `r` `g` and `b` are not assigned any values, before calling their respective `set` methods.

Hence, only **garbage values** get stored in `rval` `bval` and `gval` of `pix`.

This is why the `assert`s:

```
assert(pix.getRed() == 6);
assert(pix.getBlue() == 6);
assert(pix.getGreen() == 4);
```

are bound to fail.

**EDIT:**

To correct this, you need to read the input, that you just put into the stream, into the variables `r` `g` and `b`.

So, change your `std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& out, Pixel& pix)` function like this:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& out, Pixel& pix)
{
 int r, g, b;
 out >> r >> g >> b;
 pix.setRed(r);
 pix.setGreen(g);
 pix.setBlue(b);
 return out;
}
```

Also replace:

```
in << (6,4,6);
```

in your `Pixel_test.cpp` file with:

```
in << "6 4 6";
```

because `stringstream` stores data as a `string`.

Comment: void Pixel::setRed( int r )
    {
     rval = r;
    }
    void Pixel::setGreen( int g )
    {
     gval = g;
    }
    void Pixel::setBlue( int b )
    {
     bval = b;
    }
    int Pixel::getRed( ) const
    {
     return(rval);
    }
    int Pixel::getGreen( ) const
    {
     return(gval);
    }
    int Pixel::getBlue( ) const
    {
  return(bval);
    } These are the functions that give assignments to r, g, b, but why are the last three asserts still not working

Comment: @terriyon Please always add code enclosed with `` to render it as code when it is displayed. These functions are correct, the problem is with the way you use: `in << (6,4,6);    in >> pix;`. I am editing my answer for an explanation. Please have a look at that.

Comment: @terriyon Edit Completed. Please have a look at the end of the post.